# Qual a diferença entre REPLACE INTO ou ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com a seguinte dúvida qual é a diferença entre usar `REPLACE INTO` ou `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` no mysql, não servem ambos para a mesma finalidade fazer uma alteração a um campo ou mais na base de dados? Se o objectivo for outro alguém que me esclareça.

Qual é a melhor opção para usar já agora?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `Replace` executa duas ações, primeiro ele realiza a exclusão depois a inserção, isso pode causar alguns problemas como:

- Se você tiver uma restrição de chave estrangeira apontando para essa linha - `Replace` falhará.
- Se a sua chave externa estiver configurada para exclusão em cascata, o `Replace` causará que as linhas de outras tabelas sejam excluídas
- Os campos não informados terão as informações perdidas, justamente porque ele exclui a linha se existir e insere outra no final da tabela apenas com os campos e dados passados na query.

Já utilizando o `INSERT` ... `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` este problema não ocorre, é, portante, recomendado que o escolha.

Comment: Um outro problema do `REPLACE INTO` é que os campos não informados terão as informações perdidas, justamente porque ele exclui a linha se existir e insere outra no final da tabela apenas com os campos e dados passados na `query`.

Comment: boa observação somei a resposta, obrigado. @RobertoFagundes